# Combine data table row elements into a new column as a vector

Tags: r, data.table

I need to get a vector per row containing elements of certain columns of my data.table.

I tried several combination of apply and unlist without success.

Imagine this is my data table

```
a <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")
b <- c("b1", "b2", "b3")
c <- c("c1", "c2", "c3")

DT = data.table(col1=a, col2=b, col3=c)

   col1 col2 col3
1:   a1   b1   c1
2:   a2   b2   c2
3:   a3   b3   c3
```

I need to add an extra column whose elements are a vector per each row, containing all the elements of the row.

```
   col1 col2 col3 row_as_vector
1:   a1   b1   c1    a1,b1,c1
2:   a2   b2   c2    a2,b2,c2
3:   a3   b3   c3    a3,b3,c3
```

Comment: Could you make your question more concrete? Please make a reproducible example with exact expected output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure if you want something like below

```
DT[,result := asplit(DT,1)]
```

such that

```
> DT
   col1 col2 col3 result
1:    1    a    x  1,a,x
2:    1    b    y  1,b,y
3:    1    c    z  1,c,z
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

```
DT[, result := as.list(transpose(DT))]

   col1 col2 col3   result
1:   a1   b1   c1 a1,b1,c1
2:   a2   b2   c2 a2,b2,c2
3:   a3   b3   c3 a3,b3,c3
```

Another option

```
DT[, result := unclass(transpose(DT))]
```

Comment: Thanks sindri, but I don't need strings but vectors as elements of the new column.

Comment: @user3715836 see updated solution